# HDMI to AV converter is created low-quality / fuzzy images

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, hdmi, conversion

I'm using a generic HDMI to AV converter like the following:

https://www.amazon.ca/Converter-Techole-Aluminum-Composite-Converter/dp/B0837FTD19/

And it works... sort of. The screen is replicated on any display I try (from my laptop), but the image is fuzzy. Text is hard to read. Lowering the resolution of the HDMI source (my laptop) seems to help a bit. But of course I don't want to have to run at 800x600 resolution.

Any ideas why this would happen? I have a regular generic HDMI cable and R/Y/W composite cables. Tried several sets of both. I even tried two different generic hdmi-to-av converter products.

Open to other suggestions of how I can convert HDMI to AV in a higher quality for my older screens. Thanks.

Comment: Composite video is suitable only for video.  Do not expect to render a readable high-resolution computer screen image unless you install a font intended for a low-resolution display.  Even basic VGA 640x480 is more resolution than the limits of composite video.

Comment: Damn so is there no way to display composite from my laptop in high resolution on a monitor? I know the monitor is good enough to support the higher res.

Comment: @sawdust it's a small display inside a custom device, only has AV input.. I'd be happy if I could get it to look non-fuzzy even at a lowered resolution than the computer feeding it. Edit - and I know the display itself is capable of 800x480 at least.

Comment: The composite video interface is essentially a low-pass filter, which removes high resolution information.  Displaying a low-resolution signal on any display is still a low-resolution image.  Why are you using such a converter in the first place, if it's not a standard definition television?  Composite video can look decent; I have LaserDiscs that demonstrate that a low-noise signal can be up-scaled and look good.  But that is video, not computer text.

Comment: With a low-resolution signal on a high-resolution display, the up-scaler makes a difference.  Cheap TVs and probably all computer monitors have a reputation of doing a poor job in the up-scaling department.  I rely on the DScaler program on a HTPC to upscale the analog SD Laserdisc video to a HD resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wiki on the topic of [composite video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video),

> Composite video is an analog video signal format that carries
>   standard-definition video (typically at 480i or 576i resolution) as a
>   single channel.

Other links from my search present approximately the same information. This would indicate that you are getting the best quality available from this medium of transmission.

If your older screens are limited to composite video input, that will be your limiting factor. Other input options would produce better results, although dependent on the type of input.

Comment: I'm running on a monitor that, in HDMI mode at least, supports my 1920x1080 laptop resolution perfectly. But when I switch this monitor to AV and use the converter, I get this issue. I need to use AV for my particular project.